ECS Fargate error - "Service was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements"
I am using Terraform to try and create a ECS cluster for ealen/echo-server but get a "No container instances were found in your cluster" error in ECS. According to the docs this has to do with instances not registering, but my terraform looks okay to me -
# Define each task
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "my_task_definition" {
  family                   = "${var.service_name}-task"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  memory                   = "512"
  cpu                      = "256"
  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      name         = "${var.service_name}-task"
      image        = "ealen/echo-server"
      network_mode = "awsvpc"
      portMappings = [
        {
          containerPort = 80
          hostPort = 80
        }
      ]
    }
  ])
}

# Create a service that manages the tasks
resource "aws_ecs_service" "my_service" {
  name            = "${var.service_name}-service"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.my_cluster.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.my_task_definition.arn
  desired_count   = 1

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.my_ecs_targetgroup.arn
    container_name   = "${var.service_name}-task"
    container_port   = 80
  }

  network_configuration {
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.my_ecs_security_group.id]
    subnets         = aws_subnet.my_private_subnet.*.id
  }

  depends_on = [aws_lb_listener.my_lb_listener]
}


What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for noting! I thought that's what the "requires_cabalities" config did. But I guess I was wrong, will have to look into what more is needed here. Thanks again!

Added the "launch_type" config under the service and that seemed to fix it!
